# Cannot find a logical sense

Tags: c++

i already studied c++ in school and during the last days i have been doing the beginner c++ course of codecademy. On codecademy there is an exercise in which i have to identify palindrome words and return true or false. I haven't been able to resolve it so i saw the solution and it was:

```
#include <iostream>

// Define is_palindrome() here:
bool is_palindrome(std::string text) {
  
  std::string reversed_text = "";
  
 

 for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed_text += text[i];

  }
  

  if (reversed_text == text) {
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
  
}

int main() {
  
  std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";
  
}
```

My only doubt is with this line:

```
for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed_text += text[i];
```

i know it has to do with index values but i can't understand why it has a -1.
Could somebody explain this to me?

i thanks in advance whoever read this post. i'm sorry for my english or my poor using of stacksoverflow, i'm italian and that's my first time using this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed_text += text[i];
```

**text** is basically the string that you receive as input via function. **size()** is function that returns the size of the string i.e **text.size()** so in our test cases it will return

1. **5** for **madam**
2. **3** for **ada**
3. **8** for **lovelace**

If you think about the strings as an array with exact above size then the index range will become

1. 0-4 for **madam**
2. 0-2 for **ada**
3. 0-7 for **lovelace**

So that's why the **text.size()-1** is using as the starting index of loop. **text.size()** will return the actual size of string and then **minus 1** to get the index of **last** character in string.

so behind the scene, your loop iteration will look something like below

```
for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {  //for madam
}
//aca
for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {  
}
//lovelace
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {  
}
```

I hope it clear out your confusion.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

> i know it has to do with index values but i can't understand why it has a -1.

If a string is *n* characters long, the characters in it are indexed from 0 to *n*−1.

Since the loop works with characters from the end of the string to the beginning, it starts with index `text.size() - 1`.

However, the solution you have shown is nominally inefficient. There is no reason to make a reversed copy of the string. It suffices merely to test whether each character in the first half of the string equals the character in the reflected position:

```
bool is_palindrome(std::string text)
{
    size_t e = text.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < e/2; ++i)
        if (text[i] != text[e-1-i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, `size()` returns an unsigned value, so if `text` is empty then `text.size() - 1` will yield a very large number, and thus the loop will access the string characters out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

If using a for loop to reverse the string is confusing, you could also use the reverse function

`std::string reversed_text = text;`

`reverse(reversed_text.begin(),reversed_text.end());`

which just helps flip the entire string `reversed_text` and can achieve the same result in a simpler way.

Comment: That's a new thing i learned, from now on i will use this in this type of problems. Thanks